# Host only some subdomains of my website on Azure

Tags: azure, dns, web-hosting

Let's say I have a website that is hosted on a traditional dedicated hosting:

- http://www.mycompany.com

This website has 'folders' like /area1, /area2, /area3, etc.

I'd like to host **/area1** and **/area3** on Windows Azure, and keep the other parts of the website hosted on my existing dedicated hosting.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Folders aren't subdomains (as your title suggests). You can do subdomains on Azure, but not folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subfolders will always be requested against the base host, you will not be able to serve content from the Azure instance without first hitting your www server. If you use subdomains on the other hand (like @CSharpRocks suggest) you will be able to configure separate DNS entries and thus direct traffic directly to the Azure web role without ever hitting your dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for but you can set a CNAME that points to a Web role.  You'll end up having something like this:

- http://area1.mycompany.com
- http://area2.mycompany.com

Comment: A CNAME can point to a *.cloudapp.net subdomain that is associated with a service but not to a WebRole.

Comment: ... indeed, but once in Azure a WebRole can be configured to just serve to a particular requested hostname. See Wade's post here: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/